# Can ASPX pages share code behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance

Let say I have two ASPX pages with identical server-side controls.

```
~/TemplateA/Contact.aspx
~/TemplateB/Contact.aspx
```

By default, they are mapped to their respective code-behind file.

```
~/TemplateA/Contact.aspx.cs
~/TemplateB/Contact.aspx.cs
```

Instead, I would like them to point to a single, common code-behind file, as

```
~/Classes/Contact.aspx.cs
```

I already have them inheriting from a base "Contact" function class, who exposes the whole business-logic, but I still can't figure how to refer the server-side controls of the pages into the base "Contact" class; as example, I would like to be able to write:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "Hello"
```

in my base class instead of writing it in each single .cs file.
Obviously, "textBox1" isn't a known object in my base class as it has no designer file attached.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried using partial classes?  That's what pages use, though I haven't tried to do this.  The best way would be to have a server control (all code) which these two code behinds can inherit.

Comment: @ps2goat - you a genius! I'm making some tries and it seems working - I'll keep you updated as it may be helpful to others too

Comment: @revisors: it's not a matter of simple inheritance from a base class (as clearly stated in the question), so it's different from the answers already provided in the other questions. I'll post soon with the solution that seems working, thanks to ps2goat hint

Comment: Master Pages would be useful here I think.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas like what Garrison said... from your example it looks like you are just trying to switch between templates... something that you can do with master pages and themes. That + user controls is much easier.

Comment: @Mike & Garrison yes, you have points, maybe I'm not seeing the problem in the right way but I would avoid nesting master pages (who are already there), it's a quite complex project with a lot of "rubbish" and I am trying to clean it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here it is the solution that perfectly suited my needs (thanks again ps2goat for the hint).

My basic structure of two pages was:

```
[namespace A]
Page.aspx 
Page.aspx.cs
Page.aspx.designer.cs
```

and

```
[namespace B]
Page.aspx 
Page.aspx.cs
Page.aspx.designer.cs
```

(assume i do have far more than 2 pages)

I did need to remove the .cs and .designer.cs files while being able to refer to server controls declared in the .aspx page.

This could not be possible with standard inheriting from base classes, nor using master pages: they work well, but are completely unaware of the children ASPX server controls.

So, I created a generic class file

```
[namespace COMMON]
Page.cs
```

In this file, I copied the content of both ".cs" partial class and ".designer.cs" partial class (obviously taking care of changing namespace to the new one) of either of the original namespaces (they were identical in code).

In page.aspx file, codebehind mapping was updated from "Page.aspx.cs" and "A.Page" namespace to "Page.cs" and "Common.Page" namespace.

So, files changed from these:

[Page.aspx] (one instance for each namespace)

```
<%@ Page Title="Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.A.Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentB" ContentPlaceHolderID="cBody" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbTest" runat="server" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

[Page.aspx.cs] (one instance for each namespace)

```
namespace Project.A
{
    public partial class Page: BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txbTest.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

[Page.aspx.designer.cs] (auto-generated, one instance for each namespace)

```
namespace Project.A {
    public partial class Page{
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txbTest;                
    }
}
```

To these:

[Page.aspx] (one instance for each namespace)

```
<%@ Page Title="Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.cs" Inherits="Project.COMMON.Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentB" ContentPlaceHolderID="cBody" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbTest" runat="server" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

[Page.cs] (one SINGULAR instance, made by the content of old .cs and .designer files)

```
namespace Project.COMMON
{
    public partial class Page: BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txbTest.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }

    public partial class Page{
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txbTest;                
    }
}
```

Then I deleted each instance of page's .cs and .designer.cs files, leaving a structure as I needed, like:

```
~/A/Page.aspx
~/B/Page.aspx
~/COMMON/Page.cs
```

And it works like a charm!

So, finally, I can say that aspx is still a choice when projecting web software, MVC porting of this project can wait.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to say that even if it is possible its going to make things  **VERY** dirty. I would use inheritance

```
~/TemplateA/TemplateA.aspx
~/TemplateB/TemplateB.aspx
~/TemplateB/Contact.aspx
```

where TemplateA.aspx and TemplateB.aspx inherits Contact.aspx