# Add two aspx pages for single aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add two aspx pages for single aspx.cs file. Is it possible? I need to do this directly.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class PROJECT2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
}
```

PROJECT2 ASPX.CS should be used for two aspx pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not truly supported by Microsoft

I discussed this with Microsoft and here is what I got from them.

After further investigation, here are the results. Due to the manner in which Intellisense works, we cannot support Intellisense for scenarios involving a shared code behind on the aspx.cs files. There are two different approaches that one can take to deal with this scenario. The option supported in VS is using either AppCode or UserControll for the common code elements and then calling those methods to achieve a common code base. The second option involves using the CodeBehind in the manner that you are currently using it (without Intellisense), and assuming that the code is correct with respect to both design pages, the code should compile correctly since it is an ASP.NET supported scenario. Thank you for your feedback.

So here what that means

```
Intellisense will not work with both the pages, but only with one page
your code will compile only if both the controls are on both the pages!
```

This really is against the idea of having a shared codeBehind file. My scenario will most likely be two slight different pages which uses same code behind. But for Microsoft, two slightly different pages, can not use the same codebehind file

Ideal Scenarios should be

```
Intellisense should pick controls in both the pages
Code should compile if the the control that is accessed is present in either of the two pages.
```

Answer (score 0):

So here it is the solution that perfectly suited my needs (thanks again ps2goat for the hint).

My basic structure of two pages was:

```
[namespace A]
Page.aspx 
Page.aspx.cs
Page.aspx.designer.cs
```

and

```
[namespace B]
Page.aspx 
Page.aspx.cs
Page.aspx.designer.cs
```

(assume i do have far more than 2 pages)

I did need to remove the .cs and .designer.cs files while being able to refer to server controls declared in the .aspx page.

This could not be possible with standard inheriting from base classes, nor using master pages: they work well, but are completely unaware of the children ASPX server controls.

So, I created a generic class file

```
[namespace COMMON]
Page.cs
```

In this file, I copied the content of both ".cs" partial class and ".designer.cs" partial class (obviously taking care of changing namespace to the new one) of either of the original namespaces (they were identical in code).

In page.aspx file, codebehind mapping was updated from "Page.aspx.cs" and "A.Page" namespace to "Page.cs" and "Common.Page" namespace.

So, files changed from these:

[Page.aspx] (one instance for each namespace)

```
<%@ Page Title="Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.A.Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentB" ContentPlaceHolderID="cBody" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbTest" runat="server" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

[Page.aspx.cs] (one instance for each namespace)

```
namespace Project.A
{
    public partial class Page: BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txbTest.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

[Page.aspx.designer.cs] (auto-generated, one instance for each namespace)

```
namespace Project.A {
    public partial class Page{
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txbTest;                
    }
}
```

To these:

[Page.aspx] (one instance for each namespace)

```
<%@ Page Title="Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.cs" Inherits="Project.COMMON.Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentB" ContentPlaceHolderID="cBody" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbTest" runat="server" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

[Page.cs] (one SINGULAR instance, made by the content of old .cs and .designer files)

```
namespace Project.COMMON
{
    public partial class Page: BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txbTest.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }

    public partial class Page{
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txbTest;                
    }
}
```

Then I deleted each instance of page's .cs and .designer.cs files, leaving a structure as I needed, like:

```
~/A/Page.aspx
~/B/Page.aspx
~/COMMON/Page.cs
```

And it works like a charm!

Taken from [Can ASPX pages share code behind file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391818/can-aspx-pages-share-code-behind-file)